# DataReader and SQLCommand

Tags: c#, .net, connection, datareader, sqlcommand

As they say on the radio - long time listener first time caller....

Here's my issue. VS 2005 SQL Server 2005 Database. Windows Forms app. C#. Big table - 780K records. I'll call it the source table. Need to loop through the source table, and for each record do something with another table, then write back to the source table that it was completed. I haven't got as far as updating the second table yet...

I loop through all records of the source table using a datareader using connection object A. For each record I build an update statement to update the source table to indicate this record has been processed - and use a SQL Command against connection object B to do this uodate. So different connection objects because I know the dataReader wants an exclusive.

Here's the issue. After processing X records - where X seems to be about 60 - the update timesout.

While writing this - funny how this happens isn't it - my brain tells me this is to do with transaction isolation and / or locking...i.e. I'm reading through the source records using a datareader but changing those records...I can see this causing problems with different transaction isolations so I'll look into that...

Anyone seen this and know how to solve it?

Cheers

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more detail, the possibilities for solutions are very numerous.  As iivel noted, you could perform all of the activities within the database itself -- if that is possible for the type of operations you must perform.  I would just add that it would very likely be best to do such a thing using set-based operations rather than cursors.

If you must perform this operation outside of the database, then your source query can be executed without any locks at all, if that is a safe thing to do in your case.  You can do that by setting the isolation level or by simply appending `with (nolock)` after your table name / alias in the query.

There are several other options as well.  For instance, you could operate in batches, instead, such as pulling 1000 records at a time from the source table into memory, disconnecting, and then performing whatever operations and updates you need.  Once all 1000 records are processed, work on another set of 1000 records, and so on, until all records in the queue have been processed.

Comment: Can't do it within the database - tons of logic RE updating the second table which I want to write in C# - and already have some of the code for. I tried nolock before coming back here and that has solved the issue. Why is the next question - executing the query used by the reader with nolock does not block the writer - so what is this telling us when we don't use nolock - that the source records are locked for the duration of the datareader?

Comment: Yes, the records are likely locked with a shared lock for reading (i.e., to ensure that they are consistent for the duration of reading), so no update can be performed on the locked records.  Other connections would be able to view the records, but just not modify them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set the Command Timeout propery on the command object.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't have the select/updates in a cursor and return a final result tally to the app? If the process belongs in the the DB it is best to keep it there.

Alternately updating the command timout as John mentionted is your only other bet.

Comment: thanks for the post - see my other answers. It's not a timeout issue - some locking / transaction issue which was fixed by using nolock on the source. Cheers pete